# Access elements of a vector inside class functions

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, vector

Pretty simple question here, if i have a vector like the following, where Person is a class and 'person' are the objects,

```
std::vector<Person> person(2);
person.at(0)= Person("John");
person.at(1) = Person("David");
```

How could i access the elements of this vector inside a different class and perform operations such as displaying the names of each person?

```
for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
         cout<<person[i].Display_Name()<<endl;
    }
```

Assuming that Display_Name is a simple return 'name' function. Is this actually possible without declaring the vector inside the function where i am displaying the names in the loop?

Comment: It very much depends on the relationship between the two classes. You probably want to pass the vector as a parameter to the function that needs it, in the usual manner.

Comment: how would i go about this so that cout<<person[0].Display_Name()<<endl; will display 'John'? and so on for each object in the vector

Comment: Depending on how your code is supposed to be structured, probably by passing the vector as a parameter to the function that needs it, in the usual manner. Your introductory book should explain how function parameters work.

Comment: thanks for the help and quick responses, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your methods have a restricted visibility (private, protected) calling Display_Name() should just work.

Note: It is C++ common practice to use camelCase and start methods with lower-case: `Person::displayName`